# webform upload field template

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

For drupal's file_managed widget I created my own "[theme_file_widget](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.field.inc/function/theme_file_widget/7)" function.

I need to do the same for webform's file widget but I don't know what theme hook to use. Any ideas?